# An expression for fictitious words becoming widely adopted in reality

Tags: expressions

Occasionally, a fictitious (sometimes deliberately so, sometimes as a new word to describe a new concept) word finds popularity in the real world.

Famously, Shakespeare introduced a number of such previously-fictitious words into the English language, including "elbow," "eyeball," "mimic," and "arouse," which had few recorded appearances before their debuts in his works.

Less prominently, the TV show *The Simpsons* introduced the words "cromulent" and "embiggens" as part of a self-referential gag in the early 90s, and these words are now appearing with their presumed meanings in various places around the internet. While the adoption rate's pretty low and I haven't been keeping track of all the appearances of these words, an [Ars Technica article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/802-eleventy-what-a-deep-dive-into-why-wi-fi-kind-of-sucks/) has a reference to *cromulent* in the caption of an image:

> D-Link's DI-514 802.11b router. It was a perfectly cromulent router for its time... but those were dark days, friend, dark days indeed.

Does this kind of permeation of made-up words into the real-world vocabulary have any kind of associated expression?

Comment: When a candidate word is accepted into the lexicon, it is a neologism and has been coined. People often argue passionately about when this should be considered to have taken place.

Comment: How do we know whether Shakespeare invented "elbow," "eyeball," "mimic," and "arouse," or whether these were just considered low-class words before his time, and so did not appear much in literature? I suspect the latter is the case.

Comment: @PeterShor this is likely. They're often attributed to him becase (AFAIK) there aren't records of those words before him. That said, I was just using those words as a (hopefully useful) example.

Comment: The new term is *coined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Enter the lexicon

Is the phrase most often used in this way.

You can read more about [lexicon here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon)

> Lexicalization is the process in which
>   new words, having gained widespread usage, enter the lexicon...

Answer (score 0):

Paul [Dickson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dickson), an American writer on language and culture published a [book](http://time.com/82601/the-origins-of-writerly-words/)   in 2014 in commemoration of Shakespeare's 450th birthday. In it he discusses literary neologisms which are new words (neologisms) with a literary origin.

Appropriately enough he coined a word for literary neologism. The word was authorism.  As far as I know, dictionaries have yet to respond to this new word  so, for now, literary neologism may still be preferred by some.

Comment: Collins says that the word 'authorism' meaning 'the state or condition of being an author' has existed since at least the early 1800s. A DIY polyseme seems even less acceptable than a new DIY 'word'.

Comment: Perhaps that is why it hasn't really caught on.